# Meaning of Triple Dots [...] in Flutter Syntax

Tags: flutter, syntax

Can someone please clarify what is the meaning and usage of "..." in Flutter?

I wanted to learn about "triple dots" used in Flutter syntax. After some reading I found out that the word I was looking for was "spreading".

```
Widget _build() {
  List<Widget> children = [
    Text("first child"),
    Text("second child"),
    Text("third child"),
  ];

  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      ...children,
      Text("fourth child"),
    ],
  );
}
```

If I didn't have the `...` right before the `children,` it will give an error `The element type 'List<Widget>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.`

I just thought that someone should post a question about it. What is "..." in flutter syntax? What does it mean?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Dart 2.3 introduced the spread operator (...) and the null-aware spread operator (...?), which provide a concise way to insert multiple elements into a collection.

For example, you can use the spread operator (...) to insert all the elements of a list into another list:

```dart
var list = [1, 2, 3];
var list2 = [0, ...list];
assert(list2.length == 4);
```

If the expression to the right of the spread operator might be null, you can avoid exceptions by using a null-aware spread operator (...?):

```dart
var list;
var list2 = [0, ...?list];
assert(list2.length == 1);
```

For more details and examples of using the spread operator, see the [spread operator proposal](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.3/spread-collections/feature-specification.md).

Answer (score 2):

I used to have this problem. I solved this problem by adding .toList(); to the List Widget.

```
Widget _build() {
List<Widget> children = [
Text("first child"),
Text("second child"),
Text("third child"),
].toList();

return Column(
children: <Widget>[
  ...children,
  Text("fourth child"),
],
);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: my code is actually working. i just want someone to post a clear definition and usage of "..." but thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

`spread operator (...)` is used to provide a way to assign values to Collections, more commonly it found inside the column to render its child.

```
List<String> values = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            ...values.map((value) {
              return Text(value);
            }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

**Output:**

[image]