# What does "..." in Dart mean?

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax

I saw this code, but found no explanation for what "..." means.

```
return ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                if (bookCards != null) ...bookCards,
              ],
            );
```

Comment: This is actually probably a better dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57194452/meaning-of-triple-dots-in-flutter-syntax

Answer (score 2):

It is called **Spread Operator.** It was included in dart from **Dart 2.3**.

How to use it?
Consider the below as the basic example of how to use Spread Operator (`...`) in dart.

```
var var1 = [0,1,2,3,4];
var var2 = [6,7,8,9];
var var3 = [...var1,5,...var2];

print(var3);
```

It prints `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`